# Send Email to GoDaddy using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, godaddy-api

I am using below code to send email to webmail GoDaddy and it is working fine from my local machine and when deployed on client server it is not working.

Below is my code :

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("xyz@com");
message.From = fromAddress;                        
message.To.Add("abc@gmail.com");
message.Subject = "test Message";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "we are here";
smtpClient.Host = "mail.trustwellhospitals.com";   
smtpClient.Port = 25; 
smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

Comment: What server is it running on? Does the account it's running under have network access?

Comment: At the end, make sure you call `Dispose` on `message` and `smtpClient`.  Failing to do so could potentially affect subsequent send mail calls.

Comment: Check port 25 is blocked or not, you can change to port 587 as an alternative.

Comment: All is working in my local machine but when i deploy it on server is not working

Comment: @Virender Have you contacted your hosting provider? Maybe there is special settings from your provider.